# Large factorial division

Tags: factorial

If I want to divide $n!$ by $c^x$ but without simply inputting all in a calculator, what would be the best way to do so?

Some example: There are $25!$ atoms on a table. Each second $11^9$ are swept away. How many seconds does it take until all atoms are gone?

EDIT: Looking for a more pen and paper approach.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{25!}{11^9}=\frac{25}{11}\frac{24}{11}\frac{23}{11}\frac{22}{11}\frac{21}{11}\frac{20}{11}\frac{19}{11}\frac{18}{11}\frac{17}{11}16!$$

If you calculate all the fractions first, then multiply by 16!, then you might not overflow your calculator.  It's still a huge number, 16 digits before the decimal point.

Comment: I probably didn't make it clear enough in my question, but I'm looking for a pen & paper approach. So approximations are OK.

Comment: Then take logs.

Comment: Realized that now. That's to say, realized the right method of doing so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about what you mean by the "best" way.  Avoid arithmetic overflow or underflow?  Reduce round-off error?  Press fewer buttons?  In general, numerical computation has a number of issues that affect the result.

Since you've asked for a pen and paper approach, a good way to "simplify" your result may be to write
$$
\frac{25!}{11^9}=
\frac{25\cdots22\cdots11\cdots1}{11\cdots11},
$$
where the denominator is the product of nine $11$s.  You can cancel two of the $11$s in the denominator with the $11$ and $22$ in the numerator, leaving a $2$ instead of $22$ (since $22=2\cdot11$).  Unfortunately, since $11$ is a prime number, this all the cancellation that's possible.

Edit: You mentioned in a comment to another answer that approximations are fine, so I may have mistaken what you meant by a "pen and paper" approach.  Logarithms and Stirling's approximation are good ideas, but there are still numerical issues, so you may need to better define what you mean by the "best" way.

Answer (score 1):

By brain kicked in:

$\log(\frac{16!}{11^9}) = \log(x)$

$\log(16!)-\log(11^9) = \log(x)$  use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) on the factorial and solve for x.

Comment: This is very good, but you want to spell Sterling as Stirling so people can look up the approximation more easily.

Comment: Fixed and linked to the Wiki site.